# org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject - possible break tag issue

Tags: android, json

Currently creating a login/ signup service for an Android app. I am getting this error when hitting the log in button which should redirect to the main activity. Tested that all is well server side which seems to be working. Within the log cat this caught my eye:

```
Login Response: <br />
                                                                             <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
                                                                             <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp64\www\android_login_api\login.php on line <i>17</i></th></tr>
                                                                             <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
                                                                             <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
                                                                             <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0023</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>243336</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\android_login_api\login.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\login.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
                                                                             </table></font>
```

I thought it was this break tag is causing an issue but I don't know where its located, so that I can fix it, if it is of course whats going wrong?

Reading from the logcat it says its located at com.example.xxx.android_login D/RegisterActivity:

Anyone else had a similar problem or know where this tag is located?

Comment: Can you post your json response that you are getting on your device?

Comment: It seems like there is an error on the response.

Comment: Your API is not working.

Comment: @raktale Json error : Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Your response in not coming proper, thats why getting json exception, becuase you are converting this response to json, and that is not converting.

Comment: @DevendraSingh API tested with Advanced Rest Client and returning 200. New regsitered users are also showing in the database.

Comment: Are you using `Volley`? May be you are not sending required parameters to the API. Post your code.

Comment: @JamesMarshall-Osborne Can you please paste your json response as string, you may find in place of it some HTML is being returned.

Comment: I've just noticed:

    Undefined index: name in C:\wamp64\www\android_login_api\login.php on line <i>17</i>

Been and checked the database and the name column is in caps not lower case. Updated the php file, solved that particular error only to now have a "End of input at character 0 of" error which I am now going to look into. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

Your API Not working and the JSONObject output should be in the form of

```
{
    "Your FieldName": "Value"
}
```